# Checking for contains in many-to-may field when doing a query in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose I have the following model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
```

Let's say I have a view that takes an user and an article as an argument. I want to get all the blogs for that user and for each one check if the article is included in the blogs articles or not. So not filter by the article but just check if it is included for each blog returned by a query filtering for all blogs by that user.

I'm wondering what is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, the Django ORM can handle many-to-many filters just the same.

So, I'm thinking something like this:

```
user_blogs = Blog.objects.filter(owner=user)

user_blogs_with_article = user_blogs.filter(articles=article)
```

Comment: thanks, what about if I have user_blogs = Blog.objects.filter(owner=user)[0:10]? would I have to query each and every one individually?

Comment: No, you could something like: `Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=[blog.pk for blog in user_blogs]).filter(articles=article)`.